# Wnh does gcc generate extra xchg instructions, and one nop at the end?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Code sample:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        return 0;
}
```

Compile with command: `gcc -m32 -g  -o main main.c`

This is the assembly from `objdump`:

```
080483db <main>:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 80483db:       55                      push   ebp
 80483dc:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp

        return 0;
 80483de:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
}
 80483e3:       5d                      pop    ebp
 80483e4:       c3                      ret    
 80483e5:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
 80483e7:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
 80483e9:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
 80483eb:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
 80483ed:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
 80483ef:       90                      nop
```

Why does gcc add all the `xchg ax, ax` and final `nop` there? I notice that without adding `-m32`, then those `xchg ax, ax` instructions are removed, but nop still presents:

```
0000000004004d6 <main>:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  4004d6:       55                      push   rbp
  4004d7:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  4004da:       89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
  4004dd:       48 89 75 f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi

        return 0;
  4004e1:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
}
  4004e6:       5d                      pop    rbp
  4004e7:       c3                      ret    
  4004e8:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  4004ef:       00
```

Comment: They are not even reachable. Probably data.

Comment: Code is padded with "dummy" bytes to reach the next paragraph (16 byte) boundary `0x4004F0`. In 32-bit version `xchg ax,ax` is used as 2-byte padding, `nop` as 1-byte padding.

Comment: ... although the rationale behind it is not related to the legacy concept of "16-byte paragraph" (the latter being relevant only to old segmented-memory DOS platforms).

Comment: Your disassembler is being confusing.  `66 90` is still just a NOP.  The assembler uses a different choice of NOP-generation strategy in 64-bit code for various obscure reasons which don't matter since those NOPs will never be executed.